# Windows 7 sync (offline files): how to ignore .tmp files

Tags: windows-7, sync, offline-files

I use Windows 7 sync (offline files) to synchronize my laptop with a server work folder.

However, sync center is giving me "sync conflicts" on the .tmp files created by Excel and Word etc. It is not a major deal breaker, but still annoying. Is there any way to disable syncing of these files?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could never actually sync them, but you can disable the message!

Hmm.. there was an ExclusionErrorSuppressionList in XP.. not sure if it applies, but check here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811660

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\NetCache\ExclusionErrorSuppressionList]
"\\\\*\\*\\*\\*.PST"=dword:00000000
"\\\\*\\*\\*\\*.SLM"=dword:00000000
"\\\\*\\*\\*\\*.LDB"=dword:00000000
"\\\\*\\*\\*\\*.MD*"=dword:00000000
"\\\\*\\*\\*\\*.DB*"=dword:00000000
"\\\\*\\*\\*\\*.TMP"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\NetCache\ExclusionErrorSuppressionList]
```

Never had much success with that TBH!

But this does the trick, it tells the syncer not to notify unless there is an error!

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Syncmgr]
"KeepProgressLevel"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Syncmgr]
```

NOTE: The KeepProgressLevel Value Name can have the following data values:

```
1 - Pause on errors.

2 - Pause on warnings.

3 - Pause on errors and warnings.

4 - Pause and display INFO.
```

From: http://forums.msrportal.com/archive/index.php?t-21514.html